# My bitnami wordpress hosted on AWS asking for ftp details to update or install plugins

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, plugins, permissions, bitnami

I'm just entering cloud from shared hosting. I tried to host a wordpress website on aws bitnami. After staging the site to live.. It asks ftp details to update my plugin I had already added..

```
define ('FS_METHOD','DIRECT');
```

to wp config file and I changed the permissions even to 0777.
Here is the sudo stat of my wp-includes folder

```
bitnami@ip-172-31-29-45:~$ sudo stat /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content
  File: '/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content'
  Size: 4096            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: ca01h/51713d    Inode: 518813      Links: 7
Access: (0777/drwxrwxrwx)  Uid: ( 1000/ bitnami)   Gid: (    1/  daemon)
Access: 2019-03-26 17:39:22.042806561 +0000
Modify: 2019-03-26 17:09:52.135002773 +0000
Change: 2019-03-26 17:39:11.891037496 +0000
 Birth: -
bitnami@ip-172-31-29-45:~$
```

But It still asks for FTP details to update my plugins and other related stuffs. Please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Just open Ftp and edit **wp-config.php** and add this code on the top, Now no need to add **FTP** Details, Please Vote our answer

```
 define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami Engineer here,

Probably there is one folder inside the htdocs one that doesn't have the correct permissions. Can you run these commands modify the permissions of all the folders and files inside the htdocs folder?

```
sudo chown -R bitnami:daemon /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs
sudo chmod -R g+w /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs
sudo chmod 640 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-config.php
```

Thanks

Comment: Ran these comments.. But still no luck Bro.. Please help

Comment: Same problem here. Running these commands also didn't help. Bitnami docs seems to be out of date and now my instance is messed up ¬¬

Comment: Could you please provide more information about the error you are getting? You will probably find more log lines in the Apache's log file (`/opt/bitnami/apache2/logs/error_log`).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, but the user wasn't bitnami, it was: daemon (just like the group)

Bear in mind that at least in my case,  my bitnami installation the `wp-content` folder was a symlink, so I had to enter the symlink path, and then there run the `chown` command

```
sudo chown -R daemon:daemon /home/bitnami/stack/wordpress
sudo chown -R daemon:daemon /bitnami/wordpress/wp-content
```